# Switching rows of matrices and its effect on the value of the determinant.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

[image]

I think there is a mistake here for the second determinant.

When you switch rows twice, I believe you get the same determinant as the initial matrix. So the answer should be 3, not -3...

Please confirm this as my background in determinants is weak.

Comment: You're correct.

Comment: Ok. I will report the mistake to my TA, saying the answer should be 3 for the second determinant asked. If anyone wants to back us up, please feel free to do so. It would be appreciated.

Comment: Yep...you're correct. And if you look at the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$, your TA can verify this for him/herself,,since there's exactly one nonzero term in the determinant of either the original matrix or the permuted one.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments: you were correct about the mistake.